# setting Cookie: JSESSIONID on client request manually

Tags: java, swing, cookies, httprequest

im making a swing application which will sign in to a server; were im using **HttpURLConnection** to submit my request and get my response.

**problem is when** the httpRequest gets to the server the "Cookie: JSESSIONID" header is there, session id is there; but the **request.getSession(false)** will always return null.

here is the code which i use to set the header on the client:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie: JSESSIONID", client.getSessionId());
```

any help would be apprectiated

Comment: sorry if I misunderstand something, but which value returns from client.getSessionId()? If it was not communicated to you by the server, how can you expect that there is a session existing on the server with this id? The cookie should be given to you by the server, not you communicating to the server what the cookie should be.

Comment: the client.getSessionId() will return a session id that was already given by the server. thank you for your time it was a syntax issue and it is solved now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(postData); 
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID", getSessionId());

//cookie.setDomain("your domain");
cookie.setPath("/");

cookieStore.addCookie(cookie); 
client.setCookieStore(cookieStore); 
response = client.execute(httppost);
```

See also this [Java: How to make a HTTP browsing session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306225/java-how-to-make-a-http-browsing-session) and this [Apache HttpClient 4.0.3 - how do I set cookie with sessionID for POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166129/apache-httpclient-4-0-3-how-do-i-set-cookie-with-sessionid-for-post-request)

Comment: i used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166129/apache-httpclient-4-0-3-how-do-i-set-cookie-with-sessionid-for-post-request of your answer and it did solve my problem with
"connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + client.getSessionId());" 
unfortunately it was just a syntax issue :S
thank you for your help and time :)

Comment: @Gazaz Nevertheless this is the correct way to do it. No possibility of syntax errors when you use the API provided for the purpose.